# Two Dependent Combo Boxes

Tags: excel, vba

**Edit:** Managed to find the solution to it thanks to fellow user @Tin Bum

I'm trying to make 2 Combo Box where the the first one (Cmb1) will show only unique values from Column 1 and then (Cmb2) will show a list of values from Column 2 that are related to Column 1.

Populating the Cmb1 has been successful however the problem lies with populating Cmb2.

```
Column 1    Column 2
1             a
1             b
1             c
2             d
2             e
```

The problem lies with populating Cmb2

```
Private Sub UserForm_Activate()
Dim wslk As Worksheet
Set wslk = Worksheets("w1")
With wslk
t1 = .Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).row

On Error Resume Next
For y = 2 To t1
Set c = .Cells(y, 2)
Set t1rng = .Range(.Cells(2, 2), .Cells(y, 2))
x = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(t1rng, c)
If x = 1 Then Cmb1.AddItem c
Next y
On Error GoTo 0
End With

End Sub

Private Sub Cmb1_Change()
Dim wslk As Worksheet
Set wslk = Worksheets("w1")

Private Sub Cmb1_Change()
Dim wslk As Worksheet
Set wslk = Worksheets("w1")

Cmb2.ListIndex = -1
If Cmb1.ListIndex > -1 Then
'Currently I am stuck over here
Cmb2.List =

**Solution:**
Dim i As Integer
    Cmb2.Clear

For i = 2 To wslk.Range("B" & Application.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row
    If wslk.Range("B" & i).Value = Cmb1.Value Then
    Cmb2.AddItem wslk.Range("C" & i)
End If

End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Side note: Descriptive variable names make debugging (or code reviewing) much easier - names like x, y, c, t1 etc are difficult to follow as they don't mean anything (unless you made them!).

Comment: @SamuelEverson Sorry, I'm new to this and was mostly copy and pasting code from the net. But will try to do that in the future.

Comment: Also, indenting your code makes it much much easier to follow

Comment: Put your code into the Exit event not into the change event. Then it is very similar code to what you already have. Your existing code checks to see if it can match c .... if c is now ComboBox2.Value you're halfway there

Comment: @TinBum I'll keep that in mind. Also, I've been trying to do that. Not sure where I did wrong though.

Comment: If you post that code too we can all look at it. In the 1st Combobox you're finding single matches (IF x=1 ...), in the Exit code you're finding multiple matches (IF x>0 ...) the CountIf range is also different

Comment: @Zainedevontay no need to be sorry! We've all learned it sometime!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This the bones of a solution for the Exit Event Code. 
It should be Ok for hundreds of rows but may be slow for thousands of rows, also you still have to workout the 2 ranges - I've arbitrarily assigned them to fixed ranges.

On the plus side it should be simple to follow

```
Dim Rng1 As Range, Rng2 As Range
Dim xCel As Range, List2 As String

Rng1 = Range("A10:A20") ' whatever Range covers your Col1 Data
Rng2 = Range("B10:B20") ' whatever Range covers your Col2 Data

List2 = ""
For Each xCel In Rng2.Cells
   If xCel.Offset(0, -1).Value = Combobox1.Value Then
      ' Add this Value to a String using VbCrLf as a Separator
      List2 = IIf(List2 = "", "", List2 & vbCrLf) & CStr(xCel.Value)
   End If
Next xCel
' Split the String into an Array of Values for ComboBox2
ComboBox2.List = Split(List2, vbCrLf)
```

It also relies on NOT HAVING CHR(13) & CHR(10) (VbCrLF) in your data

Comment: Thanks for the help! I've been trying to use your code and managed to find a way. Would love your thoughts on it.

Comment: Post your new code as an addendum to your question and then send me a message, happy to look at it.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `Dictionary` to get your unique values and also populate this on your `Initialize` `Sub`. Making this a `Public` variable in the scope of the `Userform` will allow you to then use it later on the `Change` event as well to get your list values

```
Option Explicit
Private Uniques As Object
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Dim c As Range, InputRng As Range
    Dim tmp As Variant
    Dim k As String

    Set Uniques = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    With Worksheets("w1")
        Set InputRng = .Range(.Cells(2, 2), .Cells(.Cells(.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row, 2))

        For Each c In InputRng
            k = c.Value2
            If Uniques.exists(k) Then
                tmp = Uniques(k)
                ReDim Preserve tmp(LBound(tmp) To UBound(tmp) + 1)
                tmp(UBound(tmp)) = c.Offset(0, 1).Value2
                Uniques(k) = tmp
            Else
                ReDim tmp(0)
                tmp(0) = c.Offset(0, 1).Value2
                Uniques.Add Key:=k, Item:=tmp
            End If
        Next c

        Cmb1.List = Uniques.keys
    End With

End Sub
Private Sub Cmb1_Change()
    Cmb2.ListIndex = -1
    If Cmb1.ListIndex > -1 Then
        Cmb2.List = Uniques(Cmb1.Value)
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! However I'm trying to avoid using dictionary for various reasons.

Comment: @Zainedevontay why?

Comment: I was trying to learn on how to use Dictionary since last week and couldn't understand it at all. But thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Sub Cmb1_Change()
Dim wslk As Worksheet
Set wslk = Worksheets("w1")

Dim i As Integer
    Cmb2.Clear

For i = 2 To wslk.Range("B" & Application.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row
    If wslk.Range("B" & i).Value = Cmb1.Value Then
    Cmb2.AddItem wslk.Range("C" & i)
End If
```